# How to alter the attributes of a form's fields without clearing the field values?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

So I have this html form:

```
<form action="">
        <input type="text" name="form-0-product_name" id="id-form-0-product_name">
        <input type="text" name="form-0-product_price" id="id-form-0-product_price">
        <button>Change form</button>
</form>
```

Please note the name and id attributes and how they contain "form-0". For a reason that doesn't really matter too much, I want the user to be able to click the "Change form" button and have all the instances of "form-0" change to "form-1". I came up with this javascript function that does that:

```
let button = document.querySelector("button");
let form = document.querySelector("form");

button.addEventListener("click", e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const replacedForm = "form-0";
    form.innerHTML = form.innerHTML.replaceAll(replacedForm, "form-1");
})
```

This does the trick of replacing the "form-0" strings with "form-1" ; however, it seems as though this *completely* resets the form. In other words, if the client has already typed some data into the text fields and then presses the change form button, the fields are cleared of their values. What I want to know is if there's a really efficient way to change the form's fields' attributes (mainly id and name) without clearing the values of the fields if their are values in them. Thanks and please let me know if I need to clarify.

Comment: Why do you need to replace the html to change the id/name?

Comment: I don't, but that's the reason for my question. I'm asking for a better way to do this. I'm not just trying to change the id, I'm also trying to change the name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to iterate over the elements and attributes individually.

```js
let button = document.querySelector("button");
let form = document.querySelector("form");

button.addEventListener("click", e => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const replacedForm = "form-0";
  // Select all elements with a name or id
  for (const elm of form.querySelectorAll('[name], [id]')) {
    for (const attrib of ['name', 'id']) {
      elm[attrib] = elm[attrib].replaceAll(replacedForm, "form-1");
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<form action="">
  <input type="text" name="form-0-product_name" id="id-form-0-product_name">
  <input type="text" name="form-0-product_price" id="id-form-0-product_price">
  <button>Change form</button>
</form>
```

But this is a *really strange* thing to want to do in most cases. IDs in particular should not be dynamic. Strongly consider if there's an alternative way to approach the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Oh wow. I'm embarrassed to admit it, but I've been programming in JavaScript for a year now and I had no clue you could call querySelectorAll( ) on individual elements. This solved my problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also iterate over `form.elements` and modify the attribute's `value` property

```js
const form = document.querySelector('form');

Array.from(form.elements).forEach(el => {
  Array.from(el.attributes).forEach(att => {
    att.value = att.value.replaceAll('form-0', 'form-1')
    console.log(att.value)
  });
})
```

```html
<form action="">
        <input type="text" name="form-0-product_name" id="id-form-0-product_name">
        <input type="text" name="form-0-product_price" id="id-form-0-product_price">
        <button>Change form</button>
</form>
```